# how to check if a view controller appeared after some other page in navigation controller pressed back button?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

I'm in `detailViewController` and when I press back button, it goes to `mainViewController`. How can it be determined in `mainViewController` that it was not freshly loaded but the back button was pressed in `detailViewController`?

There is a table which I want to reload in `mainViewController` and hence I'm trying to determine if it was loaded freshly or coming from `detailViewController`. Any help would be greatly appreciated and up voted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the viewWillAppear() function in your mainViewController to execute tasks before loading it.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated: animated)

    //do tasks when coming from detailViewController
}
```

EDIT:

There is another way if you don't want the code in viewWillAppear to ecexute upon fresh load, but i don't know if it's the best thing to do. In your back button handler do the following:

```
//pop the detailViewController
self.navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

//mainViewController is now at the top
//safely unpack it
if let parentVC = self.navigationController.topViewController as? mainViewController {
    //call a custom function in mainViewController which will
    //execute only the stuff you want upon back button press

    parentVC.customFunction()
}
```